# Performance issue

Tags: 12.04, apache2, php, vagrant

System details:

- Processor: Intel® Pentium® Processor 2020M (2M Cache, 2.40 GHz)
- RAM 1.8GB
- OS type: 64-bit (Release 12.04 (precise) 64-bit)
- Kernel Linux 3.2.0-32-generic
- GNOME 3.4.1

I'm a php developer. Newly Introduced to Laravel framework.
When I was using a windows system I've to install xampp
and then start apache(though it takes much load and makes system slow)
I was very happy when I switched to ubuntu 12.04 LTS because the
web server runs as a daemon (like a smooth ride).

So when I decided to use Homestead and enter into the terminal 'vagrant up'
Then Its like 'why have you done that with such a low configuration'.

So my question is what I have to do for better performance ?

1. Add 2GB more RAM (low budget option).
2. buy new system with better configuration
3. any other performance tweaks ?

Update:
[Details from system monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsmZx.jpg):
1st image -> 'vagrant up'
2nd image -> 'vagrant ssh'
3rd image -> 'vagrant halt'

Comment: ps: you can include the image in the post itself

Comment: @karel: codinglazzzy is asking specifically for hardware, and specifically for vagrant, while the question you link asks for software tweaks for overall performance.

Comment: adding RAM is good option, because it'll allow more caching. Linux distro does not required 'new best configured' PCs to work smooth. Using light-weight desktop can also speed-up. As these desktops, unlike Unity, consume less RAM & CPU

Comment: @Galgalesh Already covered that + performance tweaks in my first comment. Also already listed the hardware details in my second comment, so there's no need for embedding an elaborate screenshot.

Comment: @Karel I meant that I think this is not a duplicate. Why not edit his question and include that info there?

Comment: @Galgalesh Edit it yourself if that's what you want to do. Don't bother me to do your work for you.

Comment: @Karel I did, However, it will take a while for it to go through, because I don't have >2000 points. It was just a question to why you didn't just put it in his question initially, maybe you had a reason for that?..

Comment: @Galgalesh I'll leave it to the community to put in screenshots or even pictures of butterflies if that's what someone wants. I prefer text if possible because unlike images, text is searchable. Why post an image of terminal output when you can copy and paste the text output itself?

Comment: @Karel I completely agree. My question was about why you put the specifications as a comment rather than editing the question and putting the specifications there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18562/discussion-between-karel-and-galgalesh).

Comment: It needs 10 points to post images here. That's the prob btw

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to check the system monitor to see what the bottleneck is. open system monitor before `vagrant up` and check if ram, processor or disk usage is close to max.

From the images, It seems your RAM is the main bottleneck. Upgrading your RAM might help a lot.